# HTML-Javascript - Filechooser showing only server-side files

Tags: javascript, jquery

I hope the following isn't too tricky.

I have a simple html button. Now I want to open a filechooser as soon as a user clicks on this button.

I do this like the following:

```
$('.button').click(function()
{
        $('<input type="file"/>').attr('value');
});
```

This opens a filechooser, but I want this file-chooser to only show files on the server, not on the client. I've searched the net but couldn't find an adequate solution so far.

Any proposals are welcome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Impossible, sorry. You'd need to use server side code to make a tool that allows the end user to browse the server's files.

The file input is used for the end user to choose file(s) on their machine. It has no knowledge of the server's files.

Answer (score 1):

It's not tricky, but you can't use Input tag for it. The steps are:

1. Create a module to traverse the directory on your server and output is a JSON format in whatever server implementation that you choose
2. Create a REST endpoint to give the browser the JSON output from step #1
3. Use AJAX to call this REST webservice and get the directory listings
4. Use Tree Widget to basically build the file structure based on JSON (I am sure if you look, one is probably there already for you to use)

Comment: That was also interesting, I'm sure I will need this later. Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

There's no simple way to do it. If you use jQuery UI you can use a plugin like this:

http://gusc.lv/jquery/gcmedia.html

With a server-side scripts that outputs a list of the files you want to make browseable.

Comment: This plugin can only work with input fields unfortunately, so it is not exactly what I need. But thanks anyway!